# Add teams to sidebar on any site or to the site switcher

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange-button, sidebar, stack-overflow-for-teams

Teams only show up on Stack Overflow. We will only see the new activity indicators if we first visit Stack Overflow, or make a habit of visiting the team itself. However, some users of teams do not use Stack Overflow: for example, most diamond moderators are a member of the Moderators Q&A team but most diamond moderators across the network do not visit Stack Overflow very often or at all.

Meanwhile we've got a sidebar with a lot of space on most other sites, and a site switcher to which we cannot add our teams.

Could users in a team have the capacity to add their teams to their site switcher or to their sidebar on non-SO sites?

Comment: Note: As of [the shift to a separate domain for Teams](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384156/335251), links to individual Teams no longer show up in the sidebar of SO (or any other site).