# Stack Overflow for Teams is moving to its own domain at stackoverflowteams.com

Tags: support, announcements, stack-overflow-for-teams, domain-names

Based on our Product research and user feedback we see that sometimes when posting, users who are active in both the public community and Stack Overflow for Teams find themselves in a situation like they are talking to twins: even though you know who is in front of you, you still make the mistake of calling a twin the other name. To improve product experience and security, we are moving Stack Overflow for Teams to its own domain at stackoverflowteams.com. These changes should provide users with better visibility into whether they are working within their private team or in the global, public community.

[Read more about the changes in the Teams Help Center.](https://stackoverflow.help/en/articles/6649858-teams-domain-migration)

#### The plan

The migration process is iterative. We kicked it off in the beginning of November 2022 and will continue migrating through the end of the year. Once your team’s migration is scheduled, you will receive an email and in-application notifications. When the migration is complete, please be sure to *update any existing bookmarks or workflows* you have to accommodate the new URL (stackoverflowteams.com/c/your-team-name), as migrated teams will no longer appear in the left sidebar of stackoverflow.com.

We do not expect there to be any impact to Stack Overflow for Teams performance or the ability to access the platform during the migration. However, Teams **admins** should review and take necessary actions to ensure uninterrupted access to Teams after the migration.

#### We will appreciate your feedback

If you are a Stack Overflow for Teams user, please report any issues to [Teams Product Support](https://stackoverflow.help/en/articles/4972484-how-to-contact-support-for-stack-overflow-teams) and offer feedback to your admins or post it here on meta.

If you have any general questions about the migration process, please feel free to ask them in this question.

We hope the change will make your experience better!

Comment: In SO for Teams what is that " | " symbol doing between StackOverflow symbol and "FOR TEAMS" wording [For ref](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKNkx.png). Maybe we can remove that " 
| " symbol. Also asking because this is not the case with main SO page

Comment: @JitendraSingh That is an intentional design decision when referencing Stack Overflow in conjunction with a specific product. See https://stackoverflow.design/brand/logo/#products

Comment: Missed URL oppertunity. https://stackoverflow.teams

Answer (score 12):

Is there any option to keep some navigation link to your teams inside the SE network? For example in the site switcher dropdown?

Is there any opt-in method of receiving notifications from Teams inside the SE network? I'm assuming that all connections here are severed by default.

How will the SE moderator team be handled here, it would be rather annoying if that gets entirely decoupled and essentially invisible from SE.

Any plans of making use of the free space in the left sidebar?

Comment: Currently there is no such an option. At the same time we are evaluating how we might implement these features in the future. If you have any thoughts or ideas on how this should be implemented, please do share them!

Answer (score 6):

Is someone **with an SE account**, but **without an SO profile**, automatically able to log in to the new Teams? Or do we need to go through some registration process?

Comment: *Everyone*, even with an SO profile, has to register on the new site. It can be as simple as using an existing SO account and connecting the new account on the new site (very similar, but not the same as, creating a new profile on a new SE site), but using an existing SO/SE account is not required. Even those users with an SO account/profile could choose to have a completely separate login for the new domain. However, I'm not sure that would work and connect to an *already existing* Teams account (i.e. one which you've previously had connected to an SO account, prior to the transition).